# Database isn't updating

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-update, tableadapter

I am trying to write some data into a .MDF database that has only one table, and it's not updating after I execute this part of the code:

```
        DatabaseDataSet.MyTableRow newRow;
        newRow = databaseDataSet.MyTable.NewMyTableRow();
        newRow.name = "x";
        newRow.level = 100;
        newRow.health = 100;
        newRow.weapon = "club";
        this.databaseDataSet.MyTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

        int result = MyTableTableAdapter.Update(databaseDataSet.MyTable);
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

I am new to working with SQL databases in C#.

I'm using `TableAdapter.Update` to update the `MyTable` table in the database, I even tried writing my own query version of Update, and I also tried with the `MyTableAdapter.insert` function...and no results. I can successfully read data from a database, but when it comes to writing, I fail hard.

Comment: can you double check your MDF file (or the folder containing the file) has write permission?

Comment: Did you call SaveChanges() or sth like that?

Comment: I've checked, none of mdfs are read only, which should mean i have the permission to change them. 
Also, i didn't call SaveChanges() nor anything like that. Update should make the changes in the database alone i think.

Comment: How is it that you know you definitely aren't writing to the database?

Comment: i actually solved it back then when i asked..kind of... It updated the copy of the database. If i started the program from debug folder it worked as a charm, but from visual studio it didnt show. I guess i didnt connect well to the database or something. Afterwards i think i connected to the database via connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Update (insert and delete) will only modify the local client view of the table adapter, you have to SaveChanges in order to commit it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that you're using a compact SQL database in your project?
That means that a database file will be created wherever the program is running.
So if you run in Debug mode, you get a database in your bin/Debug folder.  Run it in Release mode and you're working on a totally different database in your bin/Release folder.  Run the installed version and it's a different database file again.

I found that out pretty quickly when I built my first .net program with a compact SQL database, the important thing to know is that the entire database is in a single file that is usually in the same directory as the running program.  Keep that fact in mind at all times and a lot of little issues like this won't bite you.